# Who wrote Tohar HaYichud?

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah, rationalism

Who wrote the anonymous rationalist debunking of kabbalah entitled [Tohar HaYichud](http://www.mesora.org/ToharHayihud.pdf)?

Comment: The site says the author is Anonymous. What more do you expect?

Comment: @DoubleAA I expect you g'oney ha'internet to do some digging!

Comment: Those who know, do not say. Seriously.

Comment: @LazerA really? Why is that so?

Comment: Because the author doesn't want his name publicized in connection with the pamphlet. Pretty much the only way to know who the author is, is to know him personally, and people who know him tend to respect him too much to go against his wishes (even if they happen to disagree with the argument that he makes in the pamphlet).

Comment: well, I guess this question will test that assertion, but I'm really surprised at that kind of attitude, usually Yidden stand by their beliefs/work

Comment: "Usually Yidden stand by their beliefs/word" — Not the Chinuch, or the Orchos Tzadikim, or the Kol Bo, etc.

Comment: @ba There is certainly a long tradition of anonymous authorship of Torah works. However, to my knowledge, none of these works are espousing a deeply controversial opinion. However, it is fairly clear that the reason the author of Tohar HaYichud doesn't want his name publicized is that he doesn't want to be subjected to the kind of attacks that such a work would attract, especially if it were known who the author was.

Comment: @ba I wonder, though, if those were anonymous on purpose.

Comment: @LazerA Gotcha! Now we know it isn't a woman! Only 50% of Jews left...

Comment: @DoubleAA The Chinuch refers to a commentary he wrote on Beitzah at the end of mitzvah 315 (298 in Frankfurt ed.), as if the reader knows who he is. (Though it's possible that he had been writing for his son, as is clear from many places, and only later decided to publish it and didn't edit that line out.)

Comment: The question could have been a lot more clear.  I did not know of the publication, when it was printed or what is was about.  I was forced to read several comments and all I really know is that the subject is controversial.  Can the question be edited to flesh this out a bit more?

Answer (score 5):

I do not know who wrote Tohar HaYichud as it is written anonymously. However it is posted on the Mesora.org website which was founded by Rabbi Moshe Ben-Chaim and the board members are:

[Rabbi Reuven Mann](http://www.ou.org/torah/author/Rabbi_Reuven_Mann#.UOWpeeQROSo): Rabbi-Young Israel of Phoenix; 
Founder-Masoret Institute for Advanced Jewish Studies for Women, New York

Rabbi Pinchas Rosenthal: Exec. Dir. -Manhattan Jewish Experience, New York
Former Principal/Teacher-Torah Academy of Suffolk County, New York

Jessie Fischbein: Jewish Studies teacher/Author, “Infertility in the Bible”

Rivka Olenick: Editor

Jonathan Herman: Contributor

There is a question from a reader regarding Tohar HaYichud which was responded to by [Rabbi Saul Zucker](http://www.mesora.org/Zohar-Halacha.html).

Comment: Why do you claim that the question regards the Tohar HaYichud?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a post on [this site](http://www.hyehudi.org/tohar-hayichud-oneness-g-d-purity/), which lists [these individuals](http://www.hyehudi.org/authors/) as authors/contributors (but does not specify who wrote the aforementioned post, the content of Tohar HaYichud is a [summary] of Rabbi Yichya Kapach‘s case against the Zohar’s authenticity. I understand this does not mean Rabbi Kapach is the author per se.