# Who is the author of "How to Get Deeper into Torah Without Falling Off the Deep End"?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, jewish-books, authorship

In a short pamphlet (which became quite famous) called "How to Get Deeper into Torah Without Falling Off the Deep End" -- first published in 1994 by Laser Pages Publishing -- the author, who goes by the title "Friedman the Tutor", provides some useful guidance for youth who are beginning their journey through the Yeshiva/Seminary system, and provides advice for avoiding many of the obstacles that people encounter in that period of growth. Some of the topics discussed include: maintaining healthy relationships, going slow, staying grounded, and having realistic expectations.

(Original pamphlet available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpeep2feu1td89h/How%20to%20Get%20Deeper%20into%20Torah%20Without%20Going%20Off%20the%20Deep%20End.pdf?dl=0). Sharing of the full pamphlet is encouraged by the author.)

What is the full name of the author? Have they published any other works? The author provided a P.O. Box in Jerusalem, 6476, but this is likely no longer accurate.

Comment: Is the publisher still active? Have you tried contacting them?

Comment: @mevaqesh I have been unable to locate any other writings under the name "Friedman the Tutor". I have not attempted sending mail to the PO Box provided above.

Comment: It appears the publisher has published a number of scientific journals in Israel.

Comment: Is there no contact info available for the publisher?

Comment: In The Environment Encyclopedia and Directory, 2001, I found the following contact information for a publisher of the same name: Laser Pages Publishing Ltd, POB 35409, Merkaz Sapir 6/ 37, Givat Shaul, Jerusalem 91352, Israel. Tel. 2-652-2226. Fax 2-652-2227

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: On the topic of authorship and Jewish books, I'd say so.

Comment: @Chaim If they have a phone number, why not give them a call? If you do, consider sharing the info here to help others, unless they specify that they don't want the information publicized.

Comment: Presumably, for whatever reason the publisher didn't put the author's name on the pamphlet, it also won't give it to an inquiring member of the public. (Unless that reason has expired.)

Comment: caution http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23296/759

Comment: What is infamous about this, may I ask?

Comment: @DonielF Infamous in the sense that it was popular in many American Yeshivot in the 90's. I don't believe verifying that statement is relevant to the main question, though.

Comment: @Chaim Famous, perhaps, but how is it infamous? (I never claimed it was. I was just seeking to understand that statement.)

Comment: https://esseragaroth.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-get-deeper-into-torah-without.html?showComment=1428853925749#c5116795999554863217 This commenter says the author is female.

Comment: https://beyondbt.com/2009/10/14/getting-deeper-into-torah-without-going-off-the-deep-end-part-1/#comment-386648 an assumption to the identity of the author is made in this comment but further down someone writes that the author was a tutor in Ohr Somayach, which contradicts the view of that comment.