# May I tell someone that I've figured out his online screen name?

Tags: halacha, internet, mussar-ethics, onaath-devarim

Without publicly revealing his identity, would merely telling someone that he "outed himself" constitute אונאת דברים?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23296/759

Comment: The term "Outed himself" must be a tech term. What does it mean?

Comment: @DanF In general, "outing someone" involves revealing confidential, true, personal information about someone against their will and without their permission. In the question I posed, the person "outed himself", by using a "screen name" on one website, and inadvertently used his real name on a different website.

Comment: In public, or in private? In private, you could be doing him the favor of warning him to delete the evidence before even more people notice. Could still be ona'ah, but with an offsetting chesed to permit it. In public, you are giving curious people motive to look around, making things worse.

Comment: I have no way of doing it privately, because that would probably lead to him revealing my screen name. Am I obligated to do him a "chesed" at the expense of my own privacy? The question remains about in public. On one forum, the person uses a screen name, which indicates that he desires a certain level of privacy. On the other forum he used his own name. What does that say?