# Is one allowed to audio/ video record someone without their knowledge or consent?

Tags: halacha, technology, phone, recording

In American law, when it comes to recording a telephone call, 38 states  allow "one party consent" - namely, as long as one person is ok with recording the call (i.e., you) the other party doesn't need to give approval or consent ([source](https://www.mwl-law.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/LAWS-ON-RECORDING-CONVERSATIONS-CHART.pdf), bottom of page 1).

Have a couple questions:

1. Would this *halachically* be allowed and why yes or no? ( ex: "**yes**"- *dina d'malchusa dina*, "**no**" *geneivas da'as*, I never would have said something if I knew I was being recorded)
2. However we rule on Q1, would that be extended to being recorded on video or would that perhaps be different?

Comment: Of course it is allowed, as you use your phone all the time to record audio/video and take pictures on the street. That's not the question, **the real question is the use of that recordings**. This is a clear overriding of לא תלך רכיל - the prohibition of gossip see https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%A5_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_-_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first question, it is mostly prohibited with some possible exceptions ([CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi) before doing this in practice). I have bolded the specific issues identified by these *poskim*. Nearly all these issues apply to your second question as well.

R Shlomo Dichovsky (“Ha’azanat Seter” in Torah Shebe’al Peh 35, p. 57) is quoted [here](http://dinonline.org/2011/03/04/recording-phone-call-phone-tapping/) as writing

> Although it would **not be permitted** to tap phones in general, and to
>   listen or publicize others’ conversations (**because of** prohibitions
>   such as **publicizing others’ secrets, the cherem of R. Gershon, heizek
>   re’iah**, and others, which are discussed by poskim), it would be
>   **permitted for the sake of saving oneself from damage**, based on the
>   principle of *avid inish dina lenafsheh*.

[businesshalacha.com](https://www.businesshalacha.com/en/newsletter/recording-conversation) writes

> In halachic literature (C.M. 228) [geneivas daas] is classically
>   described as the act of misleading and deceiving someone in a manner
>   that will cause this person to mistakenly feel morally indebted, even
>   though he is not actually indebted. Thus secretly recording someone
>   does not violate the prohibition of geneivas daas. Nevertheless **we do
>   find authorities who would consider such an act geneivas daas** (see
>   Chikekei Lev 1, Y.D. 49 and Pele Yo’etz, Geneivah).
>
> But there are additional issues to consider. This act may **possibly
>   violate the Cherem D’Rabbeinu Gershom** (Be’er Hagolah, Y.D. 334), who
>   prohibits reading other people’s correspondence. It is debatable
>   whether this ban extends to all manner of communication or whether it
>   is limited to written correspondence. It is obvious that, at the very
>   least, it constitutes a violation of **v’ahavta l’rei’acha kamocha** (see
>   Chikekei Lev ibid., which suggests this as the underlying rationale
>   behind Rabbeinu Gershom’s cherem).
>
> Additionally, some write that it is prohibited to **reveal a friend’s
>   private concerns, which is an extension of the prohibition of
>   tale-bearing (rechilus)**. If one may not tell tales to others, one may
>   certainly not seek tales for himself (Halachos Ketanos 1:6).
>
> Some contend that secretly recording conversations is a form of **hezek
>   re’iyah** — the prohibition against causing damage by gazing at another.
>   It is broadly defined as the prohibition against violating another
>   person’s privacy, even if he is aware of it, as he might be too
>   embarrassed to protest.
>
> Chazal relate that when Bilam observed that placement of the tents of
>   the Jews was done in a way that assured each one’s privacy, he
>   commented that that made them worthy to receive the Divine presence
>   (see Shulchan Aruch Harav, Nizkei Mammon 11:13). The obvious extension
>   of this principle is that secretly recording a conversation is a
>   **violation of privacy and represents a lack of tznius**.
>
> Nevertheless, **for purposes of chinuch it may be permitted to secretly
>   record a conversation when necessary** (see Rashba 1:557), for example,
>   to afford one the opportunity to prevent someone from sinning or to be
>   able to recover money that is owed to him (Pele Yo’etz).

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23297/759