# Is there any Halacha that says you should notify the person on the phone he’s on speaker?

Tags: halacha, technology, internet, derech-eretz-manners, bein-adam-lachavero

BH

Is there a Halacha that says a person should notify the person who he’s talking on the phone with that he’s on speaker so the other will know?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23297/759

Comment: "לאמור" in the Torah means that God allowed Moses to repeat what he told him to the nation. Otherwise conversations should be kept private.  Especially since the normative standard when speaking on the phone is that it is solely between the two of you. So you should let the person know that they are on speaker for all to hear

Comment: It could be geneivas daas when the speaker thinks he is speaking with you in private, while in fact, others are listening too. So, according to that, I think it would.

Comment: This might be sort of part of rabbeinu gershom's takkana on reading other's mail? Letting someone listen in on a phone call (without the speakers knowledge) would be like letting someone read mail sent to someone else without their knowledge

Comment: Yes: ואהבת לרעך כמוך

Comment: The prohibition of אונאת דברים includes surprising people